# How to find the same data in a record and do an action in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a very tricky problem : I want to identify the same records and do some actions when the records are the same.

**Exemple (e-commerce case) :**

Each products have delivery mods. I have many products in a cart, and so multiple delivery mods and they can be the same.

Goal : find each same delivery mods on a single product, and create a LogisticalOrder, to purpose to the customers a choice with multiples delivery mods :

**First LogisticalOrder :** 3 products with 1 DeliveryMoD

**Second LogisticalOrder :** 2 product with 1 other DeliveryMod

There is **2 LogisticalOrders beacause the delivery mods are not the same.**

Data specific, Products and DeliveryMods have a join table (product.delivery_mods)

**Test 1 :**

```
  @products = current_cart.products
      @delivery_mods = @products.delivery_mods
      @delivery_mods.uniq.each do |delivery_mod|
        @logistical_order = LogisticalOrder.new
        @logistical_order.products = @products
        @logistical_order.logistical_order_digits = [*('A'..'Z')].sample(2).join
        @logistical_order.save
      end
  end
```

**Test 2 :**

```
@products = current_cart.products
  @products.each do |product|
    @delivery_mod = Array.new
    @delivery_mod << product.delivery_mods
    @delivery_mod.uniq.each do |logistical_order|
      logistical_order = LogisticalOrder.new
      logistical_order.order = @order
      logistical_order.products = @products
      logistical_order.save
    end
  end
end
```

It's not working, it's creates as many LogisticalOrder as there is DeliveryMods, while **it should create LogisticalOrder as many as there is differents DeliveryMods.**

Do you have any solutions for this issue and identify same records ?

Please help me :) 
Many thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Same, what is the question?

Comment: sorry, i was editing @jvillian

Comment: ""3 products can be delivered with DeliveryMod(1) / 1 product can be delivered with DeliveryMods(2,3,4).". What?

Comment: @jedi it was confusing, edition done.

Comment: "Goal : find each same records" What records? Products or delivery mods of a single product?

Comment: find each same delivery mods on a single product @jedi

Comment: So you want to create a LogisitcaOrder per delivery mod? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @jedi more specificly, 5 products in the cart. 3 have the Delivery mod A. 2 have the Delivery mod B. I want to create 2 logistical order because there is 2 differents delivery mods on the products. Sorry it's a bit difficult for me to explain..

Comment: What is LogisitcalOrder? What fields does it have? Is it a model? If yes, please paste the mode code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a many to many relationship right? A product can have 0..n delivery mods, and a delivery mod can have 0..n products, am I right?

In that case, you could start getting the delivery mods of your products, map those delivery mods to a logical order object. Example:

```
logical_orders = current_cart.products.map(&:delivery_mods).uniq.map { |dm| LogicalOrder.create(order: @order, products: dm.products, delivery_mod: dm) }
```

Step by step:

1. Get all products from your cart and convert those products to its the delivery mods and remove duplicates, so you'll have a list of delivery mods that are related to the products on your cart.

   ```
   current_cart.products.map(&:delivery_mods).uniq
   ```
2. Convert those deliver mods into a Logical order passing the attributes in a hash param. Also the #create method will create it directly on the database, so you don't to call #save manually.

   ```
   map { |dm| LogicalOrder.create(order: @order, products: dm.products, delivery_mod: dm) }
   ```
3. If you want to check which logical orders where saved successfully, you could check which of them were saved

   1. Saved logical orders:

      ```
      logical_orders.select { |lo| lo.persisted? }
      ```
   2. Not saved logical orders:

      ```
      logical_orders.reject { |lo| lo.persisted? }
      ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Juan F it's exactly what I needed (sorry for delay). But there is a bug with : `products: dm.products`, it returns me `undefined method "products" for #<DeliveryMod::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f7f61dc7d18> Did you mean? product_values` Any idea please ?

Comment: This is pseudocode, I don't know how your model is built, you must use your defined properties

Answer (score 0):

```
@products = current_cart.products
  @products.each do |product|
    @delivery_mods = product.delivery_mods
    @delivery_mods.each.uniq do |delivery_mod|
      logistical_order = LogisticalOrder.new
      logistical_order.products = delivery_mod.products
      logistical_order.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hey @jedi thanks for you answer. It's not exactly working because the action is creating as many LogisticalOrder as there is DeliveryMods records, and not as many as there is different DeliveryMods